# Height not increasing using setInterval (creating border around screen)

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I'm trying to create a border that slowly wraps around the screen. As part of this process, I'm playing around with only increasing the height of the border right now by using the setInterval method. However, I can't get the border height to increase slowly. Below is what I'm doing:

```
var i = 1;
setBorder = setInterval(borderAnimation(), 200);
function borderAnimation() {
    var border = document.getElementById("border-animation");
    border.style.height = i + "vh";
    i = i + 1;
    document.write(i);
    if(i = 100){
        clearInterval(setBorder);
    }
}
document.write(2);
```

If I change the variable i inside the function to say 5, then the height changes to that number so I know the function is being called at least once.

Similarly, document.write(i) prints only once. So if i is 1, then in the screen I see only 1; it also does not print 2 at any time even though I have document.write(2). Why is this?

After this, I intend to make it so that another div is called that goes around the top (this one is left), then another on the right then another around bottom, thus completing a border that goes around the screen. If someone has a better idea or way of achieving this, please let me know as well.

Comment: Just pass the reference to the function `borderAnimation` not the result of the function  `borderAnimation()` to `setInterval()`

Comment: That did not have any change sadly @MarkMeyer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple mistakes:

1: pass the function reference (don't call the function) to `setInterval`
2: `if(i = 100)` should be `if(i == 100)`

```js
var i = 1;
setBorder = setInterval(borderAnimation, 200);

function borderAnimation() {
    var border = document.getElementById("border-animation");
    border.style.height = i + "vh";
    i = i + 1;
    console.log(i);
    if(i == 20){
        clearInterval(setBorder);
    }
}
```

```css
#border-animation{
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<div id="border-animation"><div>
```

Comment: The second mistake where I forgot the second "=" for comparison seems to have prevented the function from being repeatedly called; and therefore, stopping the border from increasing. Thank you!